# Facebook Login Popup Box Blank

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

After making a quick static landing page we noticed that the facebook login does not work. It simply pops open a box and then automatically redirects before being allowed to sign in or decline.

Please have a look at http://www.gemroc.com/landing/index.html

That is our landing page. You can see the issue I am having there.

Again, we copied over the fb source code into this page. I am guessing that is where the issue is.

Here is what I suspect may be the cause since it was copied from the source code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
(function(d){
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];     
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    }(document));

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : 'OurAppID', 
        status     : true, 
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true  
    }); 
    Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
        Event.fire(document, 'fbinit:ready',{});
    });
};  
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
Event.observe(document, 'fbinit:ready', function(event){
    mpFBConnect.init("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=430913623675901&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gemroc.com%2Ffacebookconnect%2Flogin%2F&state=a728aaf88633a0e24b793630a1b01194&scope=email%2Cpublish_stream&display=popup");
});

mpFBConnect.facebookconnectform = '<form id="facebookconnectform" method="post" action="https://www.gemroc.com/facebookconnect/login/">' +
    '<input type="hidden" name="return" value="aHR0cDovL3d3dy5qamV3ZWwuY29tLw==" />' +
    '<input type="hidden" name="fbconnecttype" value="form" />' +
    '</form>';
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you created an app with Facebook over at developer.facebook.com and entered your app ID and secret keys into your script?

Also don't forget to change your URL from test to development server - I've been caught out with that once

**Edit**

It looks like you've just copied and pasted the output HTML by right-clicking and going to view source. This isn't the same as on run time, the snippet will be created with some more information.

Hunt down the code in the generating file and use that instead

Comment: Yes. You can see it works great at gemroc.com but not the landing page. It has to be something to do with the copy and paste job. Thanks

Comment: Literally copied the source code. However, the external js files remain the same. Let me update the post with what I copied over real quick. Thanks

Comment: See, it's all guesswork- we need to see some code :)

Comment: I just added it in the post :) Thanks

Comment: Did you grab that snippet from the HTML/php file that's serving the page or did you grab it from the front end by right clicking and viewing source?

Comment: From the fronted by viewing the source.

Comment: Viewing the source from the front end isn't the same as viewing the source code. The JavaScript you see on the other page when viewing source is not the same snippet you should put into the front end. Go have a look at the generating file and grab the source there.

Comment: That's what I figured. I'll probably have to hunt it down. Thanks

Comment: I've edited my question to suit your response. Remember to mark it as correct if you can.

Comment: Will do Scott! Thanks for confirming what I was thinking.

Comment: You might need some other dependencies (namespaces and other js files) it's been a while since I worked with that so can't comment but just bear in mind it might not be a copy paste and go job! Glad I could help

Comment: If you feel I've answered your question, please feel free to mark the answer as correct :).

Answer (score 0):

You to make such complex flow if you can do the **Facebook Login** in a very simple and the preferred way?

In `window.fbAsyncInit`, just after the `FB.init` code, write this-

```
FB.login(function(response) {
   if (response.authResponse) {
       // The person logged into your app
   } else {
       // The person cancelled the login dialog
   }
});
```

that's it. And if you don't even want to call login each time, and automatically login the user if in the session, you can use the code here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/